# Cypress to loop to td values and get a specific tr to sum (TR length will be dynamic)

Tags: while-loop, foreach, sum, cypress

I know it is not a very good option to loop and use a conditional test. However it was the only way I kinda managed to do so.

My issue is to loop correctly all the rows and wrap value in the **column 10** when it is available.

I have a dynamic table were `td=12` sometimes and `td=4` another times according with the **index tr**. like in the images
when the **td is = 12** the **column 10** will have a valeu (**the value I need to wrap and sum**)   [image]

I wrote a test that is partially working and I am not sure why it does not get the value of **column 10 when the td length =12**  and when the row has **length = 4** I need it to loop to the next line till it finds the line that has 10 columns.

```
 function textAmountToNumber(textValue) {
    const text = textValue.replace(/[£,]/g, '').trim()
    return Number(text)
  }

  let haselemente = true
  let index = 0
  let sum = 0
  const amountCol = 10

 cy.get('tbody')
        .find('tr')
        .then((e) => {
          while (haselemente) {
            const length = e.length - 1
            if (index < length) {
              cy.get('tbody')
                .find('tr')
                .eq(index)
                .then(($td) => {
                  if ($td.find('td').length < amountCol) {

                  } else {

                    cy.get('tbody')
                      .find('tr')
                      .eq(index)
                      .find('td')
                      .eq(amountCol)
                      .each(($el, index, $list) => {
                        cy.wrap($el).then((element) => {
                          sum += textAmountToNumber(element.text())
                          cy.log(sum)
                        })
                      })
                  }
                })
              index++
            } else {
              haselemente = false
            }
          }
        })
```

It break in the second row due to td = 4.

It does loops all the rows, but when the **column <= 10** it still get the value from the **index = 0 the first line** of the listl.

The reason to sum it, is to compare the total value to another element.

here is the CSS
[image]

````html
<table data-testid="section-list-card" class="table table-sm table-nowrap card-table table-hover linked-transactions-table"><thead><tr><!----> <th class="sortable"><div class="sortable">
                  COLUMN 1
                  <i class="uil uil-sort" style="font-size: 12px;"></i></div></th><th class="sortable"><div class="sortable">
                  COLUMN 2
                  <i class="uil uil-sort" style="font-size: 12px;"></i></div></th><th class="sortable" style="width: 9%;"><div class="sortable">
                  COLUMN 3
                  <i class="uil uil-sort" style="font-size: 12px;"></i></div></th><th class="">
                COLUMN 4
              </th><th class="sortable" style="width: 100px;"><div class="sortable">
                  COLUMN 5
                  <i class="uil uil-sort" style="font-size: 12px;"></i></div></th><th class="" style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">
                COLUMN 6
              </th><th class="" style="width: 10%;">
                COLUMN 7
              </th><th class="" style="width: 10%;">
                COLUMN 8
              </th><th class="" style="width: 10%;">
                COLUMN 9
              </th><th class="" style="width: 10%;">
                COLUMN 10
              </th> <th style="width: 5%;"></th></tr></thead> <tbody class="list"><tr role="row"><!----> <td><button type="button" class="btn row-collapse-expand-btn btn-link btn-sm"><i class="uil uil-angle-down" style="font-size: 20px;"></i></button> <a href="/quotes/96f37a8b-20b3-4b7c-ba1b-129db2c09bcb/show" class="" target="_blank">
          00001
        </a> <!----> <!----> <!----></td><td><a href="/clients/96f37a8a-8e46-4789-8440-5f07dcd18586/show" class="" target="_blank"><span>
  S Smith
</span></a> <!----> <!----> <!----></td><td> <!----> 
                    2022-10-17
                  </td><td><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><div>
          Amount
        </div></div> <!----> <!----></td><td> <!----> <!----></td><td><div class="text-right">
        £ 4,000.56
      </div> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 0.00
      </span> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 0.00
      </span> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 0.00
      </span> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 4,000.56
      </span> <!----> <!----></td> <td class="text-right"></td></tr> <tr class="row-tight" style=""><td colspan="3"></td> <td colspan="2"><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mr-2 uil uil-corner-down-right" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
  Gross Premium (premium)
  <!----> <div class="ml-1 con-separator-left"><a href="/entities/91d519ef-c04f-48c5-9902-2a5dd0227e59/show" class="">
      MuS
    </a></div></div> </td> <td class="text-right"><span class="balance-text text-success">
            £ 5,064.00
          </span> </td> <td colspan="4"></td></tr><tr class="row-tight" style=""><td colspan="3"></td> <td colspan="2"><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mr-2 uil uil-corner-down-right" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
   Fee
  <!----> <div class="ml-1 con-separator-left"><a href="/entities/2316df55-9aa6-4777-9587-ec77939fa1db/show" class="">
      M Smith
    </a></div></div> </td> <td class="text-right"><span class="balance-text text-danger">
            £ -354.48
          </span> </td> <td colspan="4"></td></tr><tr class="row-tight" style=""><td colspan="3"></td> <td colspan="2"><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mr-2 uil uil-corner-down-right" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
   Commision 
  <!----> <div class="ml-1 con-separator-left"><a href="/entities/d935c1b4-e733-4c22-bc40-638d25160796/show" class="">
      KKK
    </a></div></div> </td> <td class="text-right"><span class="balance-text text-danger">
            £ -708.96
          </span> </td> <td colspan="4"></td></tr><tr role="row"><!----> <td><button type="button" class="btn row-collapse-expand-btn btn-link btn-sm"><i class="uil uil-angle-down" style="font-size: 20px;"></i></button> <a href="/quotes/96f37a8b-20b3-4b7c-ba1b-129db2c09bcb/show" class="" target="_blank">
          00001
        </a> <!----> <!----> <!----></td><td><a href="/clients/96f37a8a-8e46-4789-8440-5f07dcd18586/show" class="" target="_blank"><span>
  S Smith
</span></a> <!----> <!----> <!----></td><td> <!----> 
                    2022-10-17
                  </td><td><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><div>
          Amount
        </div></div> <!----> <!----></td><td> <!----> <!----></td><td><div class="text-right">
        £ 1,591.85
      </div> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 0.00
      </span> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 0.00
      </span> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 0.00
      </span> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 1,591.85
      </span> <!----> <!----></td> <td class="text-right"></td></tr> <tr class="row-tight" style=""><td colspan="3"></td> <td colspan="2"><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mr-2 uil uil-corner-down-right" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
  Gross
  <!----> <div class="ml-1 con-separator-left"><a href="/entities/91d519ef-c04f-48c5-9902-2a5dd0227e59/show" class="">
      MuS
    </a></div></div> </td> <td class="text-right"><span class="balance-text text-success">
            £ 2,015.00
          </span> </td> <td colspan="4"></td></tr><tr class="row-tight" style=""><td colspan="3"></td> <td colspan="2"><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mr-2 uil uil-corner-down-right" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
   Fee 
  <!----> <div class="ml-1 con-separator-left"><a href="/entities/2316df55-9aa6-4777-9587-ec77939fa1db/show" class="">
      S Smith
    </a></div></div> </td> <td class="text-right"><span class="balance-text text-danger">
            £ -141.05
          </span> </td> <td colspan="4"></td></tr><tr class="row-tight" style=""><td colspan="3"></td> <td colspan="2"><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mr-2 uil uil-corner-down-right" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
  Commision
  <!----> <div class="ml-1 con-separator-left"><a href="/entities/d935c1b4-e733-4c22-bc40-638d25160796/show" class="">
      KKK
    </a></div></div> </td> <td class="text-right"><span class="balance-text text-danger">
            £ -282.10
          </span> </td> <td colspan="4"></td></tr><tr role="row"><!----> <td><button type="button" class="btn row-collapse-expand-btn btn-link btn-sm"><i class="uil uil-angle-down" style="font-size: 20px;"></i></button> <a href="/quotes/96f37a8b-20b3-4b7c-ba1b-129db2c09bcb/show" class="" target="_blank">
          00001
        </a> <!----> <!----> <!----></td><td><a href="/clients/96f37a8a-8e46-4789-8440-5f07dcd18586/show" class="" target="_blank"><span>
  S Smith
</span></a> <!----> <!----> <!----></td><td> <!----> 
                    2022-10-17
                  </td><td><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><div>
          Amount
        </div></div> <!----> <!----></td><td><a href="/invoices/96f37a8d-a552-4db2-ba10-377810f2f78a/show" class="" target="_blank">
        00001
      </a> <!----> <!----></td><td><div class="text-right">
        £ 5,000.70
      </div> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 0.00
      </span> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 0.00
      </span> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 0.00
      </span> <!----> <!----></td><td><span>
        £ 5,000.70
      </span> <!----> <!----></td> <td class="text-right"></td></tr> <tr class="row-tight" style=""><td colspan="3"></td> <td colspan="2"><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mr-2 uil uil-corner-down-right" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
  Gross Premium (premium)
  <!----> <div class="ml-1 con-separator-left"><a href="/entities/91d519ef-c04f-48c5-9902-2a5dd0227e59/show" class="">
      MuS
    </a></div></div> </td> <td class="text-right"><span class="balance-text text-success">
            £ 6,330.00
          </span> </td> <td colspan="4"></td></tr><tr class="row-tight" style=""><td colspan="3"></td> <td colspan="2"><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mr-2 uil uil-corner-down-right" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
  Fee 
  <!----> <div class="ml-1 con-separator-left"><a href="/entities/2316df55-9aa6-4777-9587-ec77939fa1db/show" class="">
      S Smith
    </a></div></div> </td> <td class="text-right"><span class="balance-text text-danger">
            £ -443.10
          </span> </td> <td colspan="4"></td></tr><tr class="row-tight" style=""><td colspan="3"></td> <td colspan="2"><div class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mr-2 uil uil-corner-down-right" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
  Agent Commision (agent_commission 14.00%)
  <!----> <div class="ml-1 con-separator-left"><a href="/entities/d935c1b4-e733-4c22-bc40-638d25160796/show" class="">
      KKK
    </a></div></div> </td> <td class="text-right"><span class="balance-text text-danger">
            £ -886.20
          </span> </td> <td colspan="4"></td></tr></tbody> <tfoot></tfoot></table>
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to filter out rows that have less than 10 `<td>`

```js
let sum = 0;
const amountCol = 10

cy.get('tbody')
  .find('tr')
  .filter(function() {
    return Cypress.$(this).find('td').length >= amountCol;  // only rows enough <td>
  })
  .each($tr => {
    const amountColumn = $tr.find('td').eq(amountCol);
    sum += textAmountToNumber(amountColumn.text())

    // cy.log(sum)  // won't work, always shows initial value of 0
    console.log(sum)  // show total as incremented
  })

cy.then(() => {
  cy.log(sum);
  expect(sum).to.eq(...)    
})
```

OR

```js
let sum = 0;
const amountCol = 10

cy.get('tbody')
  .find('tr')
  .filter(':not(.row-tight)')
  .each($tr => {
    ...
  })
```

---

#### Full test with live ammo (actual HTML)

```js
it('sums the 5th column', () => {
  
  let sum = 0;
  const amountCol = 5

  cy.get('tbody')
    .find('tr')
    .filter(':not(.row-tight)')
    .each($tr => {
      const amountColumn = $tr.find('td').eq(amountCol);

      console.log($tr.find('td'))        // take a look at the cols
      
      sum += textAmountToNumber(amountColumn.text())

      cy.log(sum)  // this does show the incremental total
    })

  cy.then(() => {
    cy.log(sum);
    expect(sum).to.eq(10593.11)    // ✅ passes
  })

});
```

Comment: the sub-total is in another table in a card table
so after cypress Sum the values on column 10 I will compare this value with the total value in another card table.

Comment: it just get the value = 0 
it does filter and show 3 rows (the length of row that has column 10)
but always wrap the value 0

Comment: Are you using `cy.then(() => cy.log(sum))` like I have?

Comment: yes, I am doing exactly you did. Btw, it does loop to all rows, filters but dont wrap any value 
`get
tbody
187
find
tr
12
188
get
tbody
189
find
tr
12
190
filter
3
191
get
tbody
192
find
tr
12
193
filter
3
194
get
tbody
195
find
tr
12
filter
3`

Comment: Let me try it, maybe I missed something.

Comment: BTW there's an easier filter based on `class="row-tight"`

Comment: will load a image for you to see how it is looping

Comment: so I no longer will need
`cy.get('tbody')
        .find('tr')
        .then((e) => {
          while (haselemente) {
            const length = e.length - 1
            if (index < length) {
loop...etc
}`
?

Comment: It's quite a complex structure. Personally I prefer the simplest possible. My code block should be all you need, provided it works! Will test it out and let you know.

Comment: I agree with you.
it kinda worked, but the SUM value is not correct. Will edit the image for you to see. Would like to know your opnion.

Comment: When the there are value on column 10 in other rows as well, it does not work, it wrap the value of only 1 row and does not sum the others. 
maybe do you know a way to fix it, so it would loop to all filter rows and get the value to sum

Comment: "In other rows as well" - I don't understand. Maybe `.filter(':not(.row-tight)')` is not the right filter to use, I can't really tell from just a screen shot of the HTML. Try it with the first filter, the more complex one.

Comment: Would make it easier to check, add HTML as text instead of picture.

Comment: will add CSS as text. 
the filter is working it shows 3 
`get ---- tbody
find  --- tr 12
filter ---- 3`
but it is wrapping and returning only the last value (the value in the last row in the case of the imagine it is return sum as **4000.56**

Comment: I added the test, looks like the `amountColumn` is #5. Left in the debugging log so you can see how to sort it out. If you go to devtools and hover the column elements, they highlight individually on the web page so you can pick which one is the correct one.

Comment: No it's 9 or 5 (they have the same values). Did you try it?

Comment: the column 10 is the column with the value. For some reason it did not copy html probably. 
the total of tr is 12 staying with a **radio as tr=0, ..... tr=10 where is the value I need, tr= 11 is a dropdown**. but you are I am able to fix it. thank you :)
I will need only to zero the `let sum` after it sum all the rows, so it can sum again when new values will be added.

Comment: better to create a new variable for the second sum.
I mean when more value is enter on the table and it is necessary to sum again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are `x` total `td` elements, with the `x-1`th being the sum, we can continuously check the new sum value.

```js
let sum = 0;
...
cy.get('td')
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    if (index < $list.length - 1) {
      sum += textAmountToNumber($el)
    }
  })
  .last()
  .invoke('text')
  .then(textAmountToNumber)
  .should(...) // whatever assertion to compare the `sum` variable to the actual sum `td` field.
```

One note: this would require changing your `textAmountToNumber` function from taking in a string (such as `$el.text()`) to taking in a JQuery element (and adding `.text()` to the element. For example:

```js
const foo = (value: string) => {
  return +value
}
// vs.
const foo = (value: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => {
  return +value.text()
}
```

I wasn't positive on what outcome you wanted to achieve, so let me know if I've missed the mark.

Comment: I am having problem to wrap the value of `column 10 when` the `td length = 12` I updated the image. how you can see in the image. There are row with value com `td=10` (I need wrap and sum this value). When the row has no value on `td=10` it need to loop to the next line till it find a value on `column 10`. Is it value I need to sum.

Comment: I try `cy.get('td')
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    if (index < $list.length - 1) {
      sum += textAmountToNumber($el)
    }
  })`
and it just wrap the value from row with index 0

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `.each()`, would be fetch td's using jQuery [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and then parse out the value and convert into a number to sum up.

It would look something like this:

```js
cy.get("td:contains(£)")
  // check if there will always be at least one row with price
  .should("have.length.greaterThan", 0)
  .then(($prices) => {
    // we get the innerText to get the float value of the text before we sum them
    const priceText = Cypress._.map($prices, (el) => el.innerText);
    const removeAllNonNumeric = (str) => str.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    const prices = priceText.map(removeAllNonNumeric).map(parseFloat);

    // sum up the prices and return the value
    const sum = prices.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);

    return sum;
  })
  // now we are working with the sum of prices and assert it equals the total you expect
  .should("eq", *expectedSumTotal*);
```

Here is a simple [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/integration/sumUpPriceInTable.md).

Comment: It is 12 columns in total and 5 of these columns have money currency - so it is not possible to use cy.get("td:contains(£)"), the td length will be 4 or 12, and I need cypress to warp the value when the length is = 12. I need the value of column 10 and when the line has length = 4 I need it to loop to the next line till it finds the line that has 10 columns

Comment: Interesting to see a screenshot. If you can show some HTML structure for the table, that would be helpful. Otherwise, it could be another shot in the dark.

Comment: will updated, however the problem is the loop all the rows and get/wrap only the value of column 10 when there is a value